# HTML Body spaced?

Tags: html, css

My body on my site is smaller on all edges for some reason, i have no idea why, here is my site to preview what the spaces / edges are doing: csgodice.co.uk, here is my css code, if you need my html i will edit it and add the html but i think its the css:

CSS:

```
@font-face{
  font-family: "coolvetica"; /* You can name the font whatever you like here */
  src: url('fonts/coolvetica rg.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Font directory and format */
}


#header {
    margin-right: 50px;
    height: 6%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #FA5858;
}

#logo {
    height: 60px;
    width: 250px;

}

#steamLogon {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#navbar {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

#navbar a {
    margin-left: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 70px;
    display: align-block;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: coolvetica;
}

#navbar .dropdown {
    margin-left: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 70px;
    display: align-block;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: coolvetica;
}

.logout {
    font-family: coolvetica;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: 25px;
    width: 160px;
    border: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
}

.logout:hover {
    font-family: coolvetica;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #262626;
    height: 25px;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #FA5858;
    border: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
}

.account {
    font-family: coolvetica;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #262626;
    height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 153px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
}

.account:hover {
    font-family: coolvetica;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #262626;
    height: 20px;
    width: 153px;
    background-color: #FA5858;
    border: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
}

/* Dropdown Button */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown-toggle:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}


#diceholder {
    height: 50%;
    width: 85%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background-color: #404040;


}

/* Account.php */

    .trade-url {
    display: align-block;
    font-family: coolvetica;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;



}
```

Comment: Put up a fiddle which works, it would be easier to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean that the body has a margin and you'd like to remove it - if so, try adding this CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: margin: 0 auto; will  center it